# Iniciante em .htaccess (caso relativamente simples)

Tags: php, htaccess

Busquei em várias fontes uma forma de aplicar corretamente uma regra simples no htaccess para interpretação de url amigável.

A princípio eu tenho os códigos abaixo:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %(SCRIPT_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(SCRIPT_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ index.php?url=$1
```

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <?php 
            $url = (isset($_GET['url'])) ? $_GET['url'] : '';
            echo $url;
         ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Seguem os resultados que obtive:

[image: Primeiro teste]

[image: Segundo teste]

Esperava que o primeiro não apresentasse nenhum texto abaixo de 'Home', e no segundo a palavra 'teste' deveria ser apresentada ao invés de 'index.php'.

Alguém sabe me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Tenta colocar `[NC,L,QSA]` ao final da `RewriteRule`. Aliás, você pode fazer em apenas uma linha as duas condições: `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`

Comment: Com essa opção, o servidor reconhece corretamente quando não envio um parâmetro, mas quando eu envio parece que ele desconsidera a regra e procura uma página com o nome enviado. Ele retorna um erro 404.

Comment: Que parâmetro seria esse?

Comment: Conforme meu código explica: Se informar a url 'localhost/site', o servidor entende que o parâmetro get URL seria vazio. Se informar a url 'localhost/site/teste', o servidor entende que o parâmetro get URL seria 'teste'.

Comment: Estranho, porque testei aqui e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Acessando `localhost` tem [este resultado](http://i.imgur.com/2kJgnF7.png) e acessando `localhost/teste` tem [este resultado](http://i.imgur.com/sq96S8I.png).

Comment: Não sei porque esse caminho não está funcionando no meu servidor, mas eu consegui resolver alterando a regra para `RewriteRule . index.php [L]` e no PHP acessando a variável `filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI')`.